# Reiterate function according to div id?

Tags: javascript

I have read some posts on Stack Overflow which have allowed me to hide a class based on whether a "td" field is empty.

However, I need to add these into a loop using the number at the end of each ID (1 - 5). Here are the scripts I need to combine:

```
<script> $(document).ready(function(){if($("#type1").text().trim() == ''){$(".testvalue1").css('display', 'none');}else {$(".testvalue1").css('display', '');}});
</script>

<script> $(document).ready(function(){if($("#type2").text().trim() == ''){$(".testvalue2").css('display', 'none');}else {$(".testvalue2").css('display', '');}});
</script>

<script> $(document).ready(function(){if($("#type3").text().trim() == ''){$(".testvalue3").css('display', 'none');}else {$(".testvalue3").css('display', '');}});
 </script>

<script> $(document).ready(function(){if($("#type4").text().trim() == ''){$(".testvalue4").css('display', 'none');}else {$(".testvalue4").css('display', '');}});
 </script>

<script> $(document).ready(function(){if($("#type5").text().trim() == ''){$(".testvalue5").css('display', 'none');}else {$(".testvalue5").css('display', '');}});
 </script>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
  <script>.
  $(document).ready(function() {
  function hideRows() {

  $("#type1").hide();
  }
    var count = parseInt(this.value);

    for (i = 5; i <= count ; i++) {
    console.log($(".testvalue" + i));
      $(".testvalue" + i).show();
    }
});
</script>
```

I am well aware my attempt is a stinking pile of a mess, however I literally can't understand how I would go about writing a loop for the scripts I supplied.
I know how to do a basic loop, just not the type I am wanting to do here.

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(i => $(".testvalue" + i).css("display", $("#type"+ i).text().trim() ? "block" : "none"))`

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate the time and the answer, this one also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic loop that can get done what your first script does.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(var i = 1; i<=5;++i){
    if($("#type"+i).text().trim() == ''){
      $(".testvalue"+i).css('display', 'none');
    }
    else $(".testvalue"+i).css('display', '');
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I really appreciate your time and effort! This works like a charm! Now I understand the process of the loop so well!